# Output from Solve is { }

Tags: output

Why is the answer (output) from the `Solve` expression shown below `{}`? Can someone please tell me what's wrong with the expression. I want to know σ1 and σ2}.

```
Solve[{S - N1 == 0, S - N2 == 0, σ1 == N1/A1, σ2 == N2/A2}, {σ1, σ2}]
```

Comment: From [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) documentation page; `{}` is returned when there are no solutions.

Comment: Solving for `{A1, A2, N1, N2, S, \[Sigma]1, \[Sigma]2}` instead of just `{\[Sigma]1, \Sigma[2]}` gives `{N1 -> S, N2 -> S, \[Sigma]1 -> S/A1, \[Sigma]2 -> S/A2}`

Comment: when i do as you write a get: 

**Solve[{S - N1 == 0, S - N2 == 0,**
  \[Sigma]1 == N1/A1, \[Sigma]2 == N2/A2}, {A1, A2, N1, N2, 
  S, \[Sigma]1, \[Sigma]2}] I get this {{N1->A1 \[Sigma]1,N2->A1 \[Sigma]1,S->A1 \[Sigma]1,\[Sigma]2->(A1 \[Sigma]1)/A2}}

Comment: dont know whats wrong

Comment: I was editing my answers too much, I accidentally deleted the part where I did `Reduce` first. But going directly with `Solve[{S - N1 == 0, 
  S - N2 == 0, \[Sigma]1 == N1/A1, \[Sigma]2 == N2/A2}, {N2, 
  S, \[Sigma]1, \[Sigma]2}]` solves to `{{N2 -> N1, S -> N1, \[Sigma]1 -> N1/A1, \[Sigma]2 -> N1/A2}}`. But mathematically I have no idea if its right, I just brute forced it until I got an output with `\[Sigma1]` and `\[Sigma]2`

Comment: Thank you very much! i solved it whit your help. =)

Comment: Note (emphasis mine): "Solve gives generic solutions only. **Solutions that are valid only when continuous parameters satisfy equations are removed.** Other solutions that are only conditionally valid are expressed as ConditionalExpression objects." (Docs.)  If you replace `Solve` by `Reduce`, you get, as part of the reduce system, two equations `N2 == S && N1 == S`, and so the solution is removed because `N1` and `N2` are treated as continuous parameters. There are two ways to solve it that treat `N1` and `N2` as variables instead of parameters....

Comment: I feel the preceding comment might be worth posting as an answer...unless there's a duplicate of this question on site already. (I may have voted to put this Q on hold too hastily.)

Comment: ...[Continuing with my answer]...Method 1: Make `N1`, `N2` variables to be solved for: `Solve[system, {\[Sigma]1, \[Sigma]2, N1, N2}]`. Method 2: Make `N1`, `N2` variables to be eliminated: `Solve[system, {\[Sigma]1, \[Sigma]2}, {N1, N2}]`.  In both methods, the symbols `N1`, `N2` are treated as variables and not as parameters.  (And these methods assume that is the intention. If not, identify which symbols are variables and which are parameters and proceed accordingly.)